# Hadoop UI Web Interface

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hadoop-plugins, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I have a small problem. I need to integrate Hadoop web interface with our web application . I just need an Hadoop interface where we can run some hadoop commands something like

```
    1 cat hadoop        dfs -cat <path>prints the file contents
2 chgrp hadoop    dfs -chgrp [-R] GROUP URI [URI …]
3 chmod hadoop  dfs -chmod [-R] <MODE[,MODE]... | OCTALMODE> URI
4 hadoop dfsadmin -setSpaceQuota 10737418240 /user/esammer
5 hadoop dfsadmin -report
6 copyFromLocal hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal <localsrc> URI
```

for this need an web interface. I already installed cloudera manager. I am using this Version: Cloudera Enterprise Data Hub Edition Trial 5.1.1 (#82 built by jenkins on 20140725-1608 git: cb9ebb729efc7929e1968b23dc6cf776086e20a7)

May i know how to get this web interface . I already configured Oozie web console .

Anyone please suggest how to implement this ..

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Hue service and then use the [Hue Job Designer](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hue-3.6.0-cdh5.1.0/user-guide/jobdesigner.html).

Comment: @j Maurer .. Thanks .. but in which service i can run hadoop commands like  MapReduce, Streaming, Java, Pig, Hive, Sqoop, Shell, Ssh, DistCp, Fs, and Email. out of there where i can hadoop commands

Comment: If you want to run those tools from a web interface, your can use Hue. If you want to run the command line equivalents, you can ssh to a server that has the hdfs  client configuration installed. This could be any server in the cluster, but is typically on a server designated as a edge node.